# Resteasy Could not find resource for relative : / of full path

Tags: java, web-services, rest, resteasy, web.xml

Is there a workaround in exposing the services without marking the scan true or adding the services into web.xml ??

Explaining the web.xml which is throwing "Could not find resource for relative : / of full path" in parts

The resteasy.scan is made false so it does not affect the loading of another parallel application deployed in the same instance

```
  <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
```

The prefix is adde for auto prefix

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/restservice</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I could avoid the "Could not find resource for relative : / of full path" by adding the individual classes in the

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.resources</param-name>
    <param-value>class.absolute.path</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The above would not be humanly possible to achieve as there are hundreds of services exposed. What is the alternative for exposing the rest services??

Additional info: All the exposed resources are in place in the war. The below complete web.xml works fine in the production environment. Im unable to comprehend why it would  throw  404 Could not find resource for relative : / of full path" when tested locally. Is there a workaround in exposing the services without marking the scan true or adding the services into web.xml ??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"> 
<display-name>TestWS</display-name>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>resteasy.servlet.mapping.prefix</param-name>
    <param-value>/restservice</param-value>
</context-param>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>classpath*:spring-*.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.spring.SpringContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>com.test.WSContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <display-name>Resteasy</display-name>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/restservice/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<resource-ref>
<res-ref-name>OracleDS</res-ref-name>
<res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
<res-auth>Container</res-auth>
<lookup-name>java:/OracleDS</lookup-name>
</resource-ref>
```